# Updating/saving data to an SQL database table using c# winforms

Tags: c#, sql, winforms

I'll start off by saying that I'm pretty inept at coding (have yet to learn how to utilize classes and how they work in depth), and that I've never worked with sql before doing this project.

The idea here is that you connect to an sql database, after which a datagridview element gets filled with data from a table called `TABLE_1` by default. The user should then be able to input, delete and save data.

The first two work operations work perfectly, but the saving is the problem. I've banged my head against a wall for about 4 days trying to get the saving to work, but I just cant get it to do so. The saving is done with the method `Button3_click`.

- Any insight as to what I should do?
- Is the main chunk of the code where you connect the part where I'm
  messing up?

```
//initialize the classes I guess, on some youtube guides they did so
SqlConnection con;
DataSet ds;
SqlDataAdapter a;
DataTable t;
SqlCommandBuilder scb;
static string tablename = "TABLE_1";
string constring;

//connect button
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        //connect using info from textboxes, connection is ok
        constring = "server=" + Server.Text + ";database=" + DB.Text + ";UID=" + UID.Text + ";password=" + Password.Text;
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constring);
        con.Open();
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        Save.Enabled = true;
        //check if table name is empty, if so default to TABLE_1
        if (textBox1.Text != "")
        { 
            tablename = textBox1.Text;
        }
        else
        { 
            tablename = "TABLE_1";
        }
        a = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM " + tablename, con);
            DataTable t = new DataTable();
            a.Fill(t);
            datagrid.DataSource = t;
        //
        label5.Text = Server.Text;
        con.Close();
    }
    catch(Exception es)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(es.Message);
    }
   
}


//save button
private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constring);
    con.Open();
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        DataTable t = new DataTable();
        a.TableMappings.Add(tablename, "t");
        scb = new SqlCommandBuilder(a);
        a.Update(t);
    con.Close();
}
```

Comment: what exception or error it shows on button click .e.g. while saving procedure

Comment: Maybe this [SqlCommandBuilder example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommandbuilder?view=dotnet-plat-ext-5.0#examples) helps.

Comment: A few years ago I created [an example project on github](https://github.com/crowcoder/CSharpCrudGrid) to demonstrate CRUD with winforms and adapters. It may be of use to you as reference. Don't get tripped up about it using Sqlite, in your own project you would just use the Sqlxxx equivalents: SqliteCommand becomes SqlCommand, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following example which sets up the adapter, dataset and table name as private variables.

Also, I recommend to never use one letter variable names as a) it's difficult to debug b) when getting into more lines of code it's going to be difficult to know what a variable is for.

Next up, using SELECT *, it' unknown if you have setup a auto-incrementing primary key which is needed to perform updates. In the example below, Id is auto-incrementing.

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsDataAdapterExample
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        private SqlDataAdapter _companiesSqlDataAdapter;
        private DataSet _companiesDataSet;
        private string _tableName = "Companies";
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            
            Shown += OnShown;
        }

        private void OnShown(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            _companiesDataSet = new DataSet();
            
            _companiesSqlDataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(
                "SELECT Id, FirstName, LastName, PhoneNumber, City FROM dbo.Companies;",
                "Data Source=.\\sqlexpress;Initial Catalog=ForumExample;" + 
                "Integrated Security=True");

            var builder = new SqlCommandBuilder(_companiesSqlDataAdapter);

            _companiesSqlDataAdapter.Fill(_companiesDataSet, _tableName);

            dataGridView1.DataSource = _companiesDataSet.Tables[_tableName];

        }

        private void SaveButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            _companiesSqlDataAdapter.Update(_companiesDataSet, _tableName);
        }
    }
}
```